# Find and return the sum of all elements of array which are either divisible by 2 or 3

Tags: java

I am new to programming and whenever I run this code I am getting a runtime error[NZEC].I dont know how to fix the error

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class divi2or3 {
    public static int findSum(int arr[])
    {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      int n = s.nextInt();
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i] = s.nextInt();
      }
      int sum=0;
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
        if(arr[j]%2==0 || arr[j]%3==0){
        sum = sum + arr[j];
        }
      }
      s.close();
      return sum;  

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace to the error

Comment: What input are you providing to this method?

Comment: should arr[i] = s.nextInt(); be arr[i] = i  instead?

Comment: You have used `arr[ ]` incorrectly, take a look over your `arr` being used and its initialisation.

Comment: Where is the main method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `findSum` to the following. You need just 1 for-loop

```
public static int findSum() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter total input ");
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int arr1 [] = new int[n];
    int sum = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter the " + n + " inputs ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = s.nextInt();
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0 || arr[i] % 3 == 0) {
            sum = sum + arr[i];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: it didn't worked

Comment: Worked for me. What issue are you facing?

Comment: Multiple markers at the end of line -----> arr[ ] = new int[n];

Comment: I've edited the answer. There is no point in passing an array as a parameter, so I've removed it and declared in within the method itself.

Comment: I got it,had to write main().Thanks man